# Найдите слово, произношение которого указано правильно

Tags: грамотная-речь

Це [р'] ковь;

Дермантин;

[д'] екларация;

Явства.

Comment: @olinka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Явная ошибка во втором примере: слово **дерматин** и пишется, и произносится без **"н"** перед **"т"**.

В слове **церковь** мягкий **[р']** -- не ошибка, а допустимое (хоть и устарелое) произношение. Но конечный согласный в этом слове оглушается: церко[ф'].

В слове **декларация** -- да, первый звук мягкий: [д'].

В слове **явства**... **См. ниже комментарий Виктора.**

===

С учётом сказанного, думаю, что ответом на задание его составители считают слово  **декларация**.

**P.S.**

А в общем-то, задание это сформулировано ну ОЧЕНЬ невнятно.

Comment: Позволю себе напомнить, что слово "яства" пишется без буквы "в" после "я"

Comment: Тьфу ты!!! СПАСИБО

И на старуху бывает проруха...